# ACL not applying default group

Tags: linux, ubuntu, acl

I want all new files / folders in the directory **/var/www/company** and all its subdirectories, to have user **company** and group **www-data**.

So I've setup my ACL like this:

```
$ getfacl /var/www/company/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www/company/
# owner: company
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:company:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

But if I create a new file e.g. `touch foo` then both user and group are set to **company**:

-rw-rw-r--+  1 company company    0 Jun 30 09:52 foo

---

```
$ getfacl foo
# file: foo
# owner: company
# group: company
user::rw-
user:company:rwx            #effective:rw-
group::r-x          #effective:r--
group:www-data:rwx      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

---

```
$ id company
uid=1000(company) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),27(sudo)
```

Comment: @Archemar, I added the infos.

Comment: Yes, this is the output of `groups` -> `company sudo`

Comment: How do you become the user `company`, do you log in as that user?

Comment: Yes, I logged in as that user.

Comment: you can't have `company` in result of `groups` and missing from `id` !? did you use `newgrp www-data` ? (I did a try, and this keep my initial group on secondary group list)

Comment: No, I never used `newgrp` I just grepped my whole history. I created the user yesterday. How can I fix it? I found these two command in the history `sudo usermod -aG www-data company` and `sudo usermod -g www-data company`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACL are not related to the primary group of new objects. The only action possible with Linux is enforcing the same group as the parent directory. For that you have to set the SGID bit for that directory:

```
chmod g+s /var/www/company
```

Comment: I have set the SGID bit with your command, but nothing has changed. Is it because I already use ACL? Aren't they compatible? `drwxr-xr-x+  5 company www-data 4,0K Jun 30 10:58 company` (/var/www/company)

Comment: Figured it out. I had to call it with sudo for unknown reasons even though the command also ran through without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a file with execution permission. Execution apart, the default seems preserved at creation.

You can try to create a folder to check if "execution" (going through) permission is here.

Comment: I created a folder: `drwxrwxr-x+  2 company company 4,0K Jun 30 10:09 bar`

Comment: Is the `umask` command output `002`?

Comment: No, Its `0022`.

Comment: Of course, you can create files with execute permission. Most programs block these permissions on file creation, though. But a compiler or `cp -p` on an executable file would not.